# Can AngularStrap bs-select be configured to be a dropup?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I tried adding the bootstrap `dropup` class to a `<select>` using `bs-select`.  It made the arrow point upwards but the menu was still displayed below the button.  Is it possible to make a `bs-select` menu be displayed above the button, like it is for a regular Bootstrap "dropup" control?  I tried to use BootstrapAdditions thinking that might help, but could not get it to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the placement option? http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##dropdowns

Comment: yes, I tried that, that was what I was talking about with BootstrapAdditions.  I added the .css file and tried adding the bottom-left, top-right, etc. to the select, and none of them seemed to have an effect.

Comment: I realize I made a mistake in configuring the element.  I needed to use data-placement="top-right" instead of simply topRight.  I was able to make the placement option to work now.  However, I did find that if I tried to also use the dropup class, it would result in the menu being either semi-transparent, or completely white.